# How do I list video files resolution?

Tags: windows, macos, video, resolution

I want to get a list of all my video files (mkv, mp4, avi etc) and their resolution, so I can see which SD video files need to be upgraded to HD. I mainly need a method (or a program) for windows, but OSX would be fine too.

I know Linux users can use this:

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -execdir mediainfo {} \; | egrep "(Complete name|Width|Height)"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**For Windows Vista (other versions can have similar features):**

If you need to see it for just one file, you can see it in the Details pane at the bottom.

If you need to see it for several files, follow 1, 2, 3* in the screenshot, then choose 'Frame height' and 'Frame width' to enable these columns. *(Tip: You can type the column names in the long list to scroll to them quickly.)*

[image]

** right-click on header to get the menu*

Comment: Thank for the greatly executed answer. This will help me out already. Is there some way I can get this exported to a list?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to do that. Sorry, but you may look for tools online.

Comment: I found a way to export the list. After the search is done, select all (CTRL+A), hold SHIFT and right-click the results. Click on Copy Path and paste in into a text document.
Another usefull tip is to search for System.Kind:Video to get all the videos.
Thanks ADTC. I accepted your answer officially.

Comment: But _Copy as path_ only seems to give the file names and paths, not the video dimensions and other details. You only needed the file names with paths?

Comment: It would be nicer to have the dimensions with it, but a list of the paths/file names will do for my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can also install `mediainfo` on OS X with for example `brew install mediainfo`.

`for f in *;do mediainfo "$f"|awk '$0~/Width|Height/{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"");printf("%s ",$0)}';echo "$f";done`

Or install `ffmpeg` and use `ffprobe`:

`mdfind kMDItemContentTypeTree=public.movie -onlyin .|while read f;do ffprobe -v 0 "$f" -show_streams -of csv|head -n1|cut -d, -f10,11|tr '\n' ,;echo "$f";done`

You might try changing `-of` (output format) to `flat`, `json`, or `xml`. `-v 0` is equivalent to `-loglevel quiet`.

`file` only displayed the dimensions for about half of the video files I tested it with. `mdls` displayed the dimensions for even fewer files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using [XYplorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/) and the ff:

1. right-click on the directory containing the video files and select "Views" - "Details."
2. right-click on the column label bar above the window and added two columns: frame width and frame rate.

From there, I clicked on either column label to sort the files through either attribute in ascending and descending order, and dragged selected files to another program to convert or rename them.